# Pool of Pawns (Chess Sliding Puzzle)

Tags: optimization, chess, sliding-blocks

The King has tired of watching the Queen swim in the Pool of Pawns. Help him return to his palace on h8 using as few moves as possible.

Only legal chess moves are allowed. Pawns are not promoted on the final rank, nor are they removed.

You can post your solutions in quasi-algebraic notation. For example, moving the queen from e6 to e7 can be notated as `Qe6e7`. Or you can post them as animations.

[image]

(Click on the image for a virtual board.)

Comment: Are pawns removed from the board when they reach the eighth row?

Comment: Nope, they just sit there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My solution has:

> 181 moves - Note that it is the same as Johnathan Allan's solution (see his for a gif of the solution), I made an arithmetic error doing it by hand and not checking with a computer (Don't believe me? Check the revision history!).

I will use P to denote pawn for nice formatting (sorry chess fans) and instead of writing multi-move chains of sliding the same type of piece in a line I will just put the start of the chain, the end of the chain and the number of moves between in brackets.

The key part is the start:

> `Rh3-e7` (9 moves) For example, this denotes `Re8-e7`, `Rf8-e8`, `Rg8-f8`, etc. round to `Rh3-h4`.
>  `Ng5-e3` (1 move)
>  `Pg2-g5` (3 moves)
>  `Rg1-g2` (1 move)
>  `Nh3-g1` (1 move)
>  `Re7-h3` (9 moves)
>  `Qe6-e7` (1 move)
>  `Pe2-e6` (4 moves)
>  `Ng1-e2` (1 move)
>  `Rc1-g1` (4 moves)
>  `Ne2-c1` (1 move)
>  `Rb8-e2` (17 moves)

This gives:

> The position shown [here](https://en.lichess.org/editor/K1RRRRRR/RPPPQPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPRPRR/RPNRRRRR_w_-_-) after 52 moves.
>  [image: Midway...]

This is the brute force part:

> `Ka8-b8` (1 move)
>  `Ra2-a8` (6 moves)
>  `Nc1-a2` (1 move)
>  `Rc8-c1` (17 moves)
>  `Kb8-c8` (1 move)
>  `Pb1-b8` (7 moves)
>  `Rd8-b1` (17 moves)
>  `Kc8-d8` (1 move)
>  `Pc2-c8` (6 moves)
>  `Re8-c2` (16 moves)
>  `Kd8-e8` (1 move)
>  `Pd2-d8` (6 moves)
>  `Rf8-d2` (14 moves)
>  `Ke8-f8` (1 move)
>  `Qe7-e8` (1 move)
>  `Pe3-e7` (4 moves)
>  `Rg8-e3` (13 moves)
>  `Kf8-g8` (1 move)
>  `Pf2-f8` (6 moves)
>  `Rh8-f2` (8 moves - note the shortcut via `g2`)
>  `Kg8-h8` (1 move)

This gives the final position of:

> [This](https://en.lichess.org/editor/RPPPQP1K/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPPPPR/RPPPRPPR/NPRRRRRR/RRRRRRRR_w_-_-)! (after another 129 moves)
>  [image: End!]

Animated solution credits to Johnathan Allan:

> [image: Animated solution]

Comment: It seems like you deserve the green check, since you posted first! When I checked your solution by hand, I didn't notice it was the same as @JonathanAllan's, and your (incorrect) count of 208 moves further prevented me from noticing... It was good that you spotted this.

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution that takes

> $181$ moves
>
>  [image: Animated solution]

Comment: how do you prepare this kind of gif files? :D

Comment: Thanks @GentlePurpleRain - I couldn't seem to compress it enough without making it tiny.

Comment: @Oray - I used Gimp - but my skills are not that great.

Comment: @Oray I used [this](http://gifmaker.me/) and [this](http://resizeimage.net/).  I think they're related sites (I got to one by following a link from the other).

Comment: @boboquack I had not looked at yours, but I see yours now has the same count. Good work!

Comment: @boboquack Funnily enough, reading yours now I see that you also had actually noted the "shortcut at g2" which I had originally missed (I had 183 posted for a few minutes and made a comment to state I'd missed it, while I fixed up my animation)!

Answer (score -2):

19 moves:

```
Re7  Rfe8  f8    Qf7   Ne6 
Rg5  R6h5  R7h6  R8h7  Rgh8
Qg8  f7    f6    Rgf5  Rhg5
R6h5 R7h6  R8h7  Qh8
```

Comment: You want to move the King (♔) to h8, not the Queen (♕). Maybe I should add a line in the instructions about which pieces are which.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It is a wrong answer but it is an answer

Comment: I thought the queen was the 'him', sorry